# Symlink script assist

Tags: symbolic-link

Symlink question:

I would like to know how I determine that the "target" will be the same place where I run the file?

I want to create a situation where wherever I run the file (target) A symlink will be created in a predetermined place that I will write in "link" Place.

```
mklink /D Link Target

New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "Link" -Target "Target"
```

Thanks in advance for the help : )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.